# What is the difference between evict and detach in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the difference between `evict` and `detach`, does `evict` detach the session anyway, if so what is the difference? I read it removes the object from the second level cache but didn't get it.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, `EntityManager.detach` and hibernate `Session.evict` do the same [thing](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_evicting_entities):

> ... remove the object and its collections from the first-level cache

From the hibernate implementation of `org.hibernate.Session` we can see that the `detach` method make an internal call of the `evict` method.

```java
public final class SessionImpl {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void detach(Object entity) {
        checkOpen();
        try {
            evict( entity );
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw exceptionConverter.convert( e );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The `session.evict()` or `entityManager.detach()` method can be used to remove the object from the `first-level` cache.

**why evict entities from the cache?**

When the `flush()` method is called, the state of the entity is saved in the database.You should evict entities if you are processing a huge number of objects and need to manage memory efficiently.

Evicting an entity from the `Hibernate` Session:

```
for(Person person : (List<Person>) session.createQuery("select p from Person p")
                     .list()) {
    dtos.add(toDTO(person));
    session.evict( person );
}
```

Detaching an entity from the `EntityManager`:

```
for(Person person : entityManager.createQuery("select p from Person p", Person.class)
        .getResultList()) {
    dtos.add(toDTO(person));
    entityManager.detach( person );
}
```

If you want to evict the entry from the `second-level` cache, you can do it following way:

```
entityManagerFactory.getCache().evict(..);
```

OR

```
sessionFactory.getCache().evict(..);
```